# Deal with session in ASP.NET C#

Tags: asp.net, session

Suppose if there are multiple sessions on single page and out of them I want to clear values of only one session then how can I achieve this. Will Session.clear() clear all sessions' value or it will create ambiguity because of multiple session?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have only one session for one user at a time. If you clear the session, you only clear the session for the current user visiting the page, not for everybody.

Comment: @Inu but what if I use session in multiple session in my code to persists value of various controls??

Comment: You have only one session per user. You can put anything you want in it(but the less is the better). You can either clear everything in it by calling Session.Clear() or either remove/add only one element by doing Session.Remove/Session.Add

Answer (score 2):

```
Session.Clear(); // Remove all keys and values from the session state collection of current user
Session.Remove("SessionName"); //Will remove particular session variable of current user
```